# How can I write a script in Google Sheets that copies a specific image from one sheet into another when prompted by a dropdown?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a workbook in Google Sheets that is used to pick the winners of college football games every week. I would like to have a dropdown to pick the winner of each game. After the winner is selected, I would like the script to copy the team's image from the sheet with all of the teams and paste it in the cell with the drop down.

The name of the sheet with all of the teams is 'Teams' and each week of games is named ' Week _'.

In my head, the best way to achieve what I want would be a script that can read the value of the dropdown and paste an image accordingly. For example, if the selection is "Michigan", the script would know that if Michigan appears anywhere in the columns E-I, it would copy A2 from the 'Teams' sheet and paste it in whatever cell "Michigan" appears in.

[Week 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnwOC.png)
[Teams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfcpW.png)

I'm new to scripting, so I haven't really tried anything outside of simply copy and paste.

Comment: If you do that you will lose the dropdown, so next week you will have to recreate the dropdown.

Comment: I have to manually add the games for each week anyway. I would add all of the dropdowns for each week.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of replacing the dropdown with an image.  You could also make another function to replace all the [CellImages](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/cell-image) with the dropdown.

I have Sheet1 as shown.  In column B I have the named range "BigTen".

[image]

And Sheet2 as shown.

[image]

Here is the example function.

```
function replaceText() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet1 = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let ranges = sheet1.getNamedRanges();
    let names = null;
    ranges.some( range => {
        if( range.getName() === "BigTen" ) {
          names = range.getRange().getValues();
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    );
    let sheet2 = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    let values = sheet2.getDataRange().getValues();
    values.forEach( (row,iRow) => {
        row.forEach( (column,iColumn) => {
            let index = names.findIndex( name => name[0] === column );
            if( index >= 0 ) {
              sheet1.getRange("A1").offset(index,0).copyTo(sheet2.getRange("A1").offset(iRow,iColumn));
            }
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in replace text: "+err);
  }
}
```

Reference

- [Sheet.getNamedRanges()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getNamedRanges())
- [Range.copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range))